# How to fix Swift 3 error ‘cannot use mutating member on immutable value: ‘loadedPost’ get only property’?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am studying Swift. I want to remove the post with `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` but it does not work. It shows:

> cannot use mutating member on immutable value: ‘loadedPost’ get only property

in the line:

```
Dataservice.instance.loadedPosts.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

How do I fix the syntax?

This is first viewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        DataService.instance.loadedPosts.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) //‘cannot use mutating member on immutable value: ‘loadedPost’ get only property’
        self.onPostsLoaded()
    }
}
```

This is array in another file:

```
class DataService {
    static var instance = DataService()

    private var _loadedPosts = [Post]()

    var loadedPosts: [Post] {
        return _loadedPosts
    }

    func savePosts() {
        let postsData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: _loadedPosts)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(postsData, forKey: "posts")
    }

    func loadPosts() {
        if let postsData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "posts") as? Data {

            if let postsArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: postsData) as? [Post] {
                _loadedPosts = postsArray
            }
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "postsLoaded"), object: nil))

    }

    func addPosts(post: Post) {
        _loadedPosts.append(post)
        savePosts()
        loadPosts()
    }
```

Comment: `loadedPosts` is read-only property by your definition, the `_loadedPosts` is read-write property, also, by your definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you only specify the public array in your singleton loadedPosts with a getter and no setter i.e with this approach you cannot mutate it. Providing a setter should work?

i.e getter only here you need a setter too.

```
var loadedPosts: [Post] {
    return _loadedPosts
}
```

maybe like this

```
var loadedPosts: [Post] {
   get{
      return _loadedPosts
   } set{
      _loadedPosts = newValue
   }   
}
```

Comment: how to make a setter?. I am new for this. Do you have answer for questions 2 and 3 too?

Comment: The code above where I say "maybe like this". Here you are providing a getter and setter. Here it is again var loadedPosts: [Post] {
   get{
      return _loadedPosts
   } set{
      _loadedPosts = newValue
   }   
}

Comment: To add get means to read the data and set means to assign the data to the variable. And in this case you want to clear out your array so you would need to able to write to the variable

Comment: This is a Swift programming fundamental. You should read Apple's free iBook, "The Swift Programming Language." It covers language basics like computed properties (what you had) and defining properties with custom getters and setters.